# Showing Detailed Error Messages

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, iis-7, asp.net-4.0

I have a little `Try Catch` block that will tell the user more detailed information when invalid data is passed to my application:

```
try
{
    //do something that throws an exception because of invalid data
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new Exception("You have invalid data");
    //throw ex;
}
```

When I run the application locally with invalid data it throws the `Exception` as expected:

```
You have invalid data
```

However when I publish it to the server it will only throw `Exceptions` like this for the same exact error:

```
There was an error processing the request.
```

**I can still run the code with valid data, so I know everything else is working correctly.**

Is there something else I have to add to my `web.config`?

Here's what I have now:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: You do realize that catching the too broad `Exception` class will cause you more problems than it will solve, don't you? (I won't even say anything about catching and throwing an exception of the exact same type just to "signal" an error condition.)

Comment: so if I `catch` that specific exception type it will work?

Comment: Two questions: (1) which version of IIS (2) if 7+ how is IIS configured - Classic or Integrated?

Comment: ex.Message will give you the message detail

Comment: @Greg Unfortunately the issue is very unclear from the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't really be showing your site visitors exceptions in this way.

If you are validating user data, then do it with [form validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479013.aspx) at the user interface level.

[Exceptions are for dealing with exceptional circumstances](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160.aspx). If you have invalid data that hasn't come from your user but has caused some exceptional circumstances then your user probably doesn't need to know the details. It's common in this situation to show a page with some kind of generic "Technical Error" message that apologises for the problem and assures them someone is looking into it.

If you want to see the details of exceptions on your server during development then you should set custom errors to off in the web.config

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off">
    </customErrors> 
</system.web>
```